# Android Touch Detection in background

Tags: android, touch, multiprocessing, listener, detection

On a text editor app, we wish to detect the touch actions- up, move and down.

We were using this below Github event,

- http://www.kpbird.com/2013/03/android-detect-global-touch-event.html

**However, there are 2 issues,**

1. When the service is on, the touch is not detected on any other screens except the service screen.
2. When we changed the touch service's active window size, now, the text editor app doesn't receive the command.

We figured that the touch is received either by the service (or) from the text editor.

How do we purely 'listen' to it and pass the touch to the editor as well?
Please help.